# Python Flask API in Docker Container

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, flask, gunicorn

I am trying to deploy a Python Flask API to AWS - and am running into some trouble - help would be appreciated!

My package looks something like the following:

```
.
├── Dockerfile
├── README.md
├── mappings
│   ├── distribution_dict.txt
│   ├── null_mappings.txt
│   └── scaling_feature_dict.txt
├── models
│   ├── MinMaxScaler.joblib
│   ├── StandardScaler.joblib
│   ├── rf_regressor.joblib
│   └── xg_regressor.joblib
├── requirements.txt
├── tests
│   └── api_test.py
├── api.py
└── wsgi.py
```

`api.py` is a Flask app which loads the models, and returns some information when called correctly. It's structured along these lines:

```py
app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app, supports_credentials=True)

model_path = 'models/'
MinMaxScaler = load(Path(model_path, 'MinMaxScaler.joblib'))
StandardScaler = load(Path(model_path, 'StandardScaler.joblib'))
rf_regressor = load(Path(model_path, 'rf_regressor.joblib'))
xg_regressor = load(Path(model_path, 'xg_regressor.joblib'))

with open('mappings/null_mappings.txt') as json_file:
    null_mappings = json.load(json_file)

with open('mappings/distribution_dict.txt') as json_file:
    distribution_dict = json.load(json_file)

with open('mappings/scaling_feature_dict.txt') as json_file:
    scaling_feature_dict = json.load(json_file)

@app.route('/predict', methods=['POST'])
def predict():

    data = request.get_json()

    information = model(data)

    response = {
        'information': information
    }

    return jsonify(response), 200

def model(X):
    # do model stuff
    return information


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I can run the app with both of the following commands locally, and in both instances I can successfully query the API with a curl command:

- `python3 api.py`
- `gunicorn wsgi:app --bind 0.0.0.0:5000`

To be clear, I don't mind whether I use gunicorn or not - I just want the API to work when deployed. It won't receive much traffic.

I have tried to containerize the api using both commands above, neither seems to work for me.

For the prior, I use the following docker file:

```
FROM python:3.7
RUN mkdir -p  /triage-prediction-api
WORKDIR /triage-prediction-api
COPY . /triage-prediction-api
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 5000
CMD ["python3"  , "api.py"]
```

However, when I run the docker image in this case - the docker container seems to last 10-40 seconds before it dies. As a note, I use the command below - when SSHing into the image to see what happens, it simply gives 'Killed' as feedback after 40 seconds (the server doesn't start).

`docker run -p 5000:5000 -d api:latest`

In the case of trying to use gunicorn, I use the following docker file:

```
FROM python:3.7
RUN mkdir -p  /triage-prediction-api
WORKDIR /triage-prediction-api
COPY . /triage-prediction-api
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 5000
CMD ["gunicorn", "wsgi:app". "--bind 0.0.0.0:5000"  , "api.py"]
```

In the case above, I attempt to send a curl request - but the request times out before hearing back from the container/server.

As a quick extra note the summed size of my models is ~1.6 GB, in the gunicorn case I did wait ~15 minutes in case the container was taking a while to load for whatever reason, however, it still didn't work.

Any help/advice here would be really appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: To check what's happening inside the docker container, you can execute firstly run bash instead of your flask API by executing `docker run -p 5000:5000 -it triage-api:latest bash` and then starting the server via the command line in the docker image (`python3 api.py`). You can then use the server as you would otherwise. The difference with running the api directly is that Flask might give you some relevant output inside the docker container.

Comment: Thanks - that's a handy tip! I just did this, and ~45 seconds after trying to start the server, I just get `Killed` as feedback.

Comment: How much memory does the machine you are running it on have. The summed size of the models is 1.6GB, when parsed this could be many times larger. Also be aware if you are using multiple processes this could also increase. The `killed` error leads me to believe the OOM killer is stopping the container.

Comment: The `killed` error indeed seems to point that the docker image is using too much memory for the allowed instance and that AWS just kills the container because of this reason.

Comment: Thanks, it was indeed a memory issue! Really appreciate the help here.